# Xamarin c# Cant get a image to work in a LinearLayout which is in a ScrollView

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin, scrollview

I have this problem in xamarin, where i make a custom view called picview which simply makes a bitmap and draws it and my activity class DatLocPage i want to have this picture in a LinearLayout which is in a Scrollview, but it doesnt seem to work. It does work when i just use SetContentView for the picview alone.

My code for the class DatLocPage is:

[Activity(Label = "")]
    class DatlocPage : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle b)
        {
            base.OnCreate(b);

```
        ScrollView upmenu = new ScrollView(this);
        upmenu.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);

        LinearLayout menu = new LinearLayout(this);
        menu.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        menu.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);

        upmenu.AddView(menu);

        picview pic = new picview(this);
        menu.AddView(pic);

        Button Back = new Button(this); Back.Text = "Back"; Back.Click += 
        klikback; menu.AddView(Back);

        this.SetContentView(upmenu);
    }
```

and for my custom view picview it is:

```
class picview : View
{
    Bitmap Plaatje;
    public picview(Context c) : base(c)
    {
        this.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
        Plaatje = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(c.Resources, Resource.Drawable.watch);
    }
    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);
        Paint verf = new Paint();
        canvas.DrawBitmap(Plaatje, 0, 0, verf);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a bunch of `LayoutParameters` on your views, which tell them how big they should be.

Take a look at this modified code:

```
ScrollView upmenu = new ScrollView(this);
upmenu.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
upmenu.LayoutParameters = 
    new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

LinearLayout menu = new LinearLayout(this);
menu.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
menu.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
menu.LayoutParameters =
    new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

upmenu.AddView(menu);

var pic = new picview(this);
pic.LayoutParameters =
    new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
        200);
menu.AddView(pic);

Button Back = new Button(this); 
Back.Text = "Back";
Back.LayoutParameters =
    new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
        50);
Back.Click += klikback; 
menu.AddView(Back);

SetContentView(upmenu);
```

Note, the `200` and `50` are in pixels, you should consider using `dp` instead. There are loads of post explaining how to convert those values.

Also the `Bitmap` in your `picview` is not disposed of and you are potentially leaking memory. So be careful with that.